# How to evalute variables in a function before converting to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I want to evaluate all the variables inside a function before converting the function to a string.

**Example:**

```js
const x = "5";

function someFunc(){
   console.log(x);
}

someFunc.toString()
```

**Output:**

```
function someFunc(){
   console.log(x);
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
function someFunc(){
   console.log("5");
}
```

I need it to work dynamically for **any** number of variables and **any** function without knowing the function or the variables first.
I prefer a solution based on metaprogramming such as reflection, but any working solution is good, including Regex.

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Comment: Possible using eval or new Function, but let's not go there...

Comment: @youdateme I would love to hear how eval or new Function can solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, at least not exactly how you describe it.

The key blocker is that there is no way to get a list of all currently-visible variables, or their values.

So at best you'd have to change the scenario a bit: start by reading a file (or other string) containing the source code you want to process. Then use a JavaScript parser (e.g. Esprima; no endorsement, just illustration) to get an AST (abstract syntax tree). Then you can do whatever transformations you like on that AST (such as: replacing constant variables with their value), and then convert the AST back to a string (which you can then write to a file, if desired).

The above should work for simple cases like the example you gave. When you look at more complicated scenarios, you'll run into obstacles and limitations though. For example:

```js
const x = 5;

function Case1() {
  let y = x;
  if (someCondition()) y++;
  console.log(y);  // what now?
}
function Case2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    console.log(i);  // what now?
  }
}
function Case3() {
  const y = {foo: 42, valueOf() { return "null"; }};
  console.log(y);  // what now?
}
function Case4() {
  const y = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "yes" : "no";
  console.log(y);  // what now?
}
```

I'm sure there are plenty more situations where this idea is difficult to put into practice.

You didn't say what your ultimate goal is, and this does have the smell of an [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Are you looking for optimization opportunities? A debugging environment? I strongly suspect that there's an easier way to accomplish whatever your actual goal is.

(Also, this doesn't have anything to do with V8, libuv, or Node.js; I'll drop tags accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = 5;

function someFunc(){
    // do something with x
    return x;
}

someFunc().toString();
```

Or

```
const x = 5;

function someFunc(){
    // do something with x
    return x.toString();
}

someFunc();
```